# Why don't I get the whole page when parsing a website?

Tags: c++, parsing, arduino, nodemcu

I want parse a https-website with an NodeMCU-Board. For that, I used the original Arduino BasicHttpsClient example. But unfortunately I don't get the full source-code of the website back. The result everytime only consist of the HTML-Header and a few lines of the HTML-Body. The rest of the website is allways missing.

Does someone knows, why this problem occurs?

```
 /**
   BasicHTTPSClientNofingerprint.ino

   1.03.2019

*/

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>
// Fingerprint for demo URL, expires on June 2, 2019, needs to be updated well before this date
// const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = {0x5A, 0xCF, 0xFE, 0xF0, 0xF1, 0xA6, 0xF4, 0x5F, 0xD2, 0x11, 0x11, 0xC6, 0x1D, 0x2F, 0x0E, 0xBC, 0x39, 0x8D, 0x50, 0xE0};

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("SSID", "PASSWORD");
}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);

    //client->setFingerprint(fingerprint);
    client->setInsecure();

    HTTPClient https;

    Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");
    if (https.begin(*client, "https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/connection.html")) {  // HTTPS

      Serial.print("[HTTPS] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = https.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = https.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      https.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS] Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Wait 10s before next round...");
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: it may have something to do with the fingerprint being expired. The comment just above the constant declaration indicates the fingerprint expires on June/2019

Comment: Sorry, it was the false codesnippet, but with the current snippet the problem is still there.